# If adverb is removed the sentence still make sense

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

I think I found a very useful approach to find an adverb in a sentence by ignoring words one by one in a sentence. E.g.,

1. He is too shy.
   He is too (shy removed, doesn't make sense)
   He is shy. (Too removed, sentence makes sense)
   Conclusion: "Too" is adverb because it is something Extra.
2. We rose very Early.
   We very early (Nope)
   We rose early (works)
   Conclusion: "Very" is adverb because sentence make a sense without it.
   Check almost any sentence, it works. Is it a good method to find an adverb in a sentence?

Comment: Only if the adverb serves as modifier to an adjective. `early` is an adverb in `We rose early` but you can't remove it, as it plays an independent role in the meaning.

Comment: "we rose" makes sense dear! or We got up

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,  why would you need to "find an adverb". If you can understand and communicate effectively, do you need to do this at all?

However this doesn't work.  At best it can find "Adjuncts", ie words that are not required for the sentence to be grammatically complete.  Some adverbs are adjuncts, but so are some adjectives and nouns.

Examples ([from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement) wikipedia)

> She put the cheese back.

"back" is an adverb, but "She put the cheese" doesn't make sense. The word "back" is required, so "back" is not an adjunct.

On the other hand

> He opened the red door.

"Red" is an adjective, but "He opened the door" is also correct and complete, so "red" is an adjunct.

Adverbs are often adjuncts, but not every adverb is an adjunct, nor is every adjunct an adverb.

Comment: For me "she put the cheese" make sense brother!